# List key values for Json data file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a very long json file, that I need  make sense of in order to query the correct data that is related to what I am interested in.  In order to do this, I would like to extract all of the key values in order to know what is available to query.  Is there an quick way of doing this, or should I just write a parser  that traverses the json file and extracts anything in-between either { and : or , and : ?
given the example:

```
[{"Name": "key1", "Value": "value1"}, {"Name": "key2", "Value": "value2"}]
```

I am looking for the values:

```
"Name"
"Value"
```

Comment: Instead of traversing the dictionary by yourself, simply do: dictionary_json.keys()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
dict = [{"Name": "key1", "Value": "value1"}, {"Name": "key2", "Value": "value2"}]

for val in dict:
    print(val.keys())
```

gives you:

> dict_keys(['Name', 'Value'])
>
> dict_keys(['Name', 'Value'])

Answer (score 2):

That will depend on if there's any nesting. But the basic pattern is something like this:

```
import json

with open("foo.json", "r") as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

all_keys = set()
for datum in data:
    keys = set(datum.keys())
    all_keys.update(keys)
```